# How many possible orders can I create for differenct lecturers with multiple presentations?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

At a seminar holds a Ph. D. $2$ presentations, each of $5$ master degree students holds $1$ presentation, each of $3$ bachelor degree students holds $2$ presentations and each of $2$ professors holds $1$ presentation.

How many possible orders of lecturers are there (not the order of presentations)?

I have written the model like that:

$\{PhD_1, PhD_1, M_1, M_2, M_3, M_4, M_5, B_1, B_1 B_2, B_2, B_3, B_3, P_1, P_2\}$

So I have calculated:

$\binom{15}{2} \cdot \binom{13}{1} \cdot \binom{12}{1} \cdot \binom{11}{1} \cdot \binom{10}{1} \cdot \binom{9}{1} \cdot \binom{8}{2} \cdot \binom{6}{2} \cdot \binom{4}{2} \cdot \binom{2}{2} = 40 864 824 000$

Unfortunately this is the wrong solution. The correct result should be $81 729 648 000$.

How can I achieve that solution?

Comment: It looks like you have half of what you want.  $\binom{2}{2}$ should be $\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}$.

Comment: Can the groups be interrupted?  Meaning, can the PhD do a presentation, then a master, then the PhD again, then a bachelor, then another master, then that same bachelor again?

Comment: @MichaelBurr : Solved my issue, thanks

Comment: @tilper : Yes, it is possible